# pugixml - check if node exists or not

Tags: c++, pugixml

I get a child node this way:

```
pugi::xml_node child = root.child("aaa")
```

I would like to check if that child node exists. Should I just call `child.empty()` ?

Comment: Remember to always add a language tag like [tag:c++] to get a wider audience to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`xml_node`](https://pugixml.docsforge.com/master/api/pugi/xml_node/#methods) class has a logical bool operator overload that allows you to check that it exists by simply calling

```
if (child) { ... }
```

and similarly an `operator!` for checking if it doesn't exist with

```
if (!child) { ... }
```